# Proving that a set is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

I have the following set In = (0, 1/n). I want to show that it is bounded but I am not sure how to do that. Please help!

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean?  Every element is less than $\frac 1n+1$, say.  Or am I misreading?

Comment: It is bounded below by $-1$ and above by $1/n + 1$, for example.

Comment: Could you tell me/do you remember what the definition of a bounded set is?

Comment: Doesn't bounded mean that there exists an upper bound and a lower bound for the set.

Comment: @gbox so can I simply state that -1 is smaller than (0,1/n) for all n in N and that 1/n + 1 is greater than 1/n for all n in N??

Comment: @MichelleDrolet Yes, sorry I was looking for the supremum and infimum

Comment: @gbox Then infimum is $0$ and supremum is $1/n$. You might want to edit your question.